# Eclipse and Android ADT error on the first app created in setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

Tags: android, eclipse

I have no word. How is possible that Google permit a thing like this?!?!
I've read a thousand of documentation before to download Eclipse + Android ADT.
After installation, like every time I made an installation of a new development system, I try to write the simple app: "hallo world".
How is possible that a simply stuff like "hallo world" don't goes?!?

First the error on "R"... that brings the error "cannot be resolved to a variable".
The fix is to add:

```
import android.R;
```

Ok... was easy. One minute on Stackoverflow and the solution is served.
Then..... BANG... immediatly the second error:

- setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  generates "activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field"
- getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  generates "main cannot be resolved or is not a field".

At this point I've read many (too much)  post over this issue, but without to see the light...

I repeat, is incredible that a system to develop app for the most widespread mobile operating system has errors at the first installation.....
Sure will be my fault...

Any suggestion is appreciated ?

Comment: How can Google prevent you from importing a wrong class and expecting it to work?

Comment: Excuse me. This are the step:
 - New Project
 - Title of project bla bla bla
 - Run project 
 - errors.... is a wizard or what? Why to start with a missing request?

Answer (score 7):

You should never import android.R.

You should instead import com.example.yourapp.R

android.R is full of resources that are baked into the Android SDK.  Your own resources are not in that class.

Comment: To be specific, <your-app-package-name>.R

Comment: if the class <your-app-package-name>.R doesn't exist, then it is because you have an error in an xml file, or an incorrectly named image in your res folder.  Check for errors in your res folder, then clean your project.

Comment: If there are no errors in XML and it still doesn't generate them try deleting your bin and gen folder and running a clean in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I've finally understood.  When I created my first project I've not used the convention  com.example.myapp but "my convention" com.myname.myapp (like I can do with xCode).
Now using import

> com.example.myapp.R;

working....
But now the question is: I can't change the word "example" in the package's name?

Comment: Your package name doesn't have to contain example.  You can change it back to com.myname.myapp, but then you will import com.myname.myapp.R.